# How to clear textbox in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I just want to clear textbox my html form. I made it and clear  but i write something in again , it seen by my function as empty. How can do it ?
 I did it like this below;

```
$('#clear').click(function(){
    document.getElementById("v1").value="";
    document.getElementById("v2").value="";
    document.getElementById("v3").value="";
    document.getElementById("v4").value="";
});
```

Comment: `$('#v1, #v2, #v3, #v4').val('')`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: if want to clear all textarea within a form try :: $('#form').find('textarea').val('');

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the jQuery **[val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)** method to set a value.

```
$('#clear').click(function(){
     $('#v1, #v2, #v3, #v4').val(''):
});
```

If you your input elements are inside a form, you also can use the `reset()` function 
to reset all form elements.

```
<form id="myForm">
  // your form elements
</form>

$('#clear').click(function(){
     $('#myForm').reset():
});
```

Comment: it said: " wait 2 minutes"

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$('#clear').click(function(){
    $("#v1,#v2,#v3,#v4").val("");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#clear').click(function(){
 $('#v1, #v2, #v3, #v4').val('');   
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If all of your inputs are wrapped in a form you could also call .reset() on that form

Answer (score 0):

If you are using JQuery:

```
$("#v1").val('');
```